# Is it possible to deploy program with Solana SDK

Tags: solana-program, program, solana-sdk

There are many examples and tutorials on how to deploy Solana account using anchor framework or the native way.

I can successfully deploy account and update its field with anchor SDK & IDL. However, I have to manually using the Solana CLI to deploy the program and its code beforehand.

I'm just wondering, since each program is also a type of account, it is possible to create program account & program executable data Account using Solana SDK?

Thanks

Comment: Also answering here:  It is technically possible, which is why the program loader bindings are available in the JS package: github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/master/packages/… -- this method isn't recommended however